# Unbelievably slow and unusable Query Store

Tags: performance, sql-server-2017, query-store, query-performance

I'm beginning with Query Store and it's with problems :-( No report of Top Resource Consuming Queries is ever generated. It just keeps saying "Waiting" for hours and hours. Query on the background (see below for an example) is not able to finish and is consuming lot of CPU. No matter how am I changing configuration options, it keeps waiting and waiting (even last hour report). Is this the reality of Query Store all over? Sounds being such a great tool but is totally unusable in real?

My Query Store size is about 1,7 GB. I'm collecting 7 day behind, in 1 hour interval and Auto Capture mode - so it seems to be reasonable settings, to me.

This is an example of a query on the background which is never finished:

```
SELECT TOP (@results_row_count)
    p.query_id query_id,
    q.object_id object_id,
    ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(q.object_id),'') object_name,
    qt.query_sql_text query_sql_text,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_duration*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) total_duration,
    SUM(rs.count_executions) count_executions,
    COUNT(distinct p.plan_id) num_plans
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
    JOIN sys.query_store_plan p ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
    JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON q.query_id = p.query_id
    JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qt ON q.query_text_id = qt.query_text_id
WHERE NOT (rs.first_execution_time > @interval_end_time OR rs.last_execution_time < @interval_start_time)
GROUP BY p.query_id, qt.query_sql_text, q.object_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct p.plan_id) >= 1
ORDER BY total_duration DESC
```

Any ideas how to make it operational?

**EDITORIAL:**
I have opened a case with Microsoft about this. We didn't solve it but came to a workaround. If I change *Query Store Capture Mode* to **All** (not using Auto mode) - then things go fine and the reports are generated in a timely fashion.

**EDITORIAL #2**
This has come to a completely different issue. The problem is not the *Capture Mode* but *Legacy Cardinality Estimator* which the database is running under.
Please vote for this Azure Feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37971781-slow-or-non-operational-query-store-under-legacy-c

**Editorial #3:**
Azure Feedback URL seems not working anymore (MS keeps changing it so nobody can track it, probably), please vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2569b74f-6825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Flush interval to disk is 15 minutes. Should I change it? Do you think it's too frequent and delaying other work with the tool?

Comment: High load during the day - maybe (define what the high load is), not in the evening / night when I'm trying it. There is quite a lot of ad-hoc plans.

Comment: 1.7 GB is made of 7 days of retention and Auto capture mode (not All). OK, the point is that I would probably myke it lower and collect just one day of data. Anyway it still mean that this tool is suitable and operational for larger environments

Comment: I reduce the collection to 1 day, updated SSMS to the latest version. Now my Query Store is "just" 350 MB. But behaviour is still the same - giving no results. Even queries that is generating, running in SSMS Windows never finish. Useless tool for me though :-(

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue, and upon investigating, discovered the root issue in slow Query Store queries is **repeated access of the in-memory TVFs**. It doesn't matter how many rows are returned from these TVFs, only the number of times they are accessed. The fix (until MS fixes underlying stuff) will be whatever you can do to nudge your plans away from reading them multiple times. Some more information in this [related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205389/never-ending-query-store-search/230869) and in my [blog post.](https://forrestmcdaniel.com/2019/02/27/slow-reports-for-query-store/)

Ultimately, I was able to fix this with a plan guide in production, using hints that I found moved the optimizer away from repeated TVF executions. Since the exact query text is required, and the query rarely finishes, I built a script that would create a plan guide while the report is running by pulling the text from exec_requests. Follow the below steps to create a plan guide.

1. Open up Top Resource Consuming Queries
2. Run the below script
   while the report is still spinning
3. Cancel the report and run
   again.

```
--USE YourDB
DECLARE @badqry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP (1) @badqry = SUBSTRING(st.text, (r.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,  
    ((CASE statement_end_offset   
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)  
        ELSE r.statement_end_offset 
    END - r.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1)
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
WHERE st.text LIKE '(@results_row_count int,@interval_start_time%'

IF @badqry IS NULL
RAISERROR('Missed the plan',16,1)

EXEC sp_create_plan_guide
@name = N'Fixing QueryStore Top Duration',
@stmt = @badqry,
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@results_row_count int,@interval_start_time datetimeoffset(7),@interval_end_time datetimeoffset(7)',
@hints = N'OPTION (HASH JOIN, LOOP JOIN)'
```

You should be able to run the above script for most of the canned Top Resource queries, but make sure to change the plan guide name if you do. Also, there's certainly a better hint out there than `HASH JOIN, LOOP JOIN`, but it's worked well enough for me so far.